# meta-data label in feature file can't be resolve in qaf 2.1.13

Tags: testng, bdd, gherkin, qaf

1. config.xml

[image: xml run configuration]

1. providerclass:

   ```
   public class CustomDataProdvider {
      @DataProvider(name="my-custom-dp")
      public static Object[][] dataProviderForBDD(){

         Map<Object, Object> rec1 = Maps.newHashMap();
         rec1.put("fruit", "grapes");
         rec1.put("color", "green");

         Map<Object, Object> rec2 = Maps.newHashMap();
         rec2.put("fruit", "banana");
         rec2.put("color", "yellow");

         return new Object[][]{ {rec1},{rec2}};
     }
   ```
2. feature:

   ```
   @TestForTest
   SCENARIO : Custom Data provider Example
   META-DATA: {"dataProvider":"my-custom-dp", "dataProviderClass":"com.qmetry.qaf.example.CustomDataProvider", "description":"Data driven test that uses custom data provider"}
      Given I am on fruits and colors activity
      When i select '${fruit}'
      Then the color should be '${color}'
   END
   ```
3. steps:

   ```
   @MetaData(value = "{'groups':['smoke']}")
   @QAFTestStepProvider
   public class TestDataProdivider {

      @QAFTestStep(description = "I am on fruits and colors activity")
      public void test(){
         System.out.println("I am on fruits and colors activity");
      }

      @QAFTestStep(description = "i select {fruit}")
      public void testfruit(String fruit){
         System.out.println(fruit);
      }

      @QAFTestStep(description = "the color should be {color}")
      public void testcolor(String color){
         System.out.println(color);
      }
   }
   ```
4. result:

   ```
   @QAFTestStep(description="META-DATA: {0}")
   public void mETADATA(Map<Object,Object> mapObj0){
      //TODO: remove NotYetImplementedException and call test steps
      throw new NotYetImplementedException();
   }
   ```

   Test ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `GherkinScenarioFactory` which expects bdd in gherkin syntax. In gherkin `Meta-data` is not supported but it is supported in qaf-bdd. You should use `com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory`. Your bdd file, let say suite1.bdd, should look like below to work with `BDDTestFactory`.

```
SCENARIO : Custom Data provider Example
META-DATA: {"dataProvider":"my-custom-dp", "dataProviderClass":"com.qmetry.qaf.example.CustomDataProvider", "description":"Data driven test that uses custom data provider","groups":{"TestForTest","smoke"}}
   Given I am on fruits and colors activity
   When i select '${fruit}'
   Then the color should be '${color}'
END
```

If you compare with original, you will observe that `@TestForTest` moved in meta-data to make your scenario compatible with qaf-bdd. Make sure your bdd file has extension `.bdd` to work with `BDDTestFactory`.

**Your config file should look like below:**

```
<suite name="QAF-Demo" verbose="0">
<test name="BDD Tests">
   <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.qmetry.qaf.example.steps" />
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="scenarios" />
   <groups>
     <run>
        <include name="TestForTest"/>
     </run>
   </groups>
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory" />
   </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Few observations:

- you are trying to add groups to steps by placing `@MetaData(value = "{'groups':['smoke']}")` in step definition class. That doesn't makes any sense. Groups should be assigned to testcase/scenario not to step(s).
- Furthermore you don't need to place `@QAFTestStepProvider` in step definition class because you are using `@QAFTestStep` to mark a method as step.

So your step definition class should look like below:

```
public class TestDataProdivider {

   @QAFTestStep(description = "I am on fruits and colors activity")
   public void test(){
      System.out.println("I am on fruits and colors activity");
   }

   @QAFTestStep(description = "i select {fruit}")
   public void testfruit(String fruit){
      System.out.println(fruit);
   }

   @QAFTestStep(description = "the color should be {color}")
   public void testcolor(String color){
      System.out.println(color);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user861594, I used the example just want to know how to use dataprovider of qaf, my scenario is that I need sql a set of data from oracle, each data would be used to post to an API to get the response, then compare the sql data with the response. I have finished this scenario used one sql data, but I need use a set of data.

Comment: This looks separate question. You can confirm current issue and post another question.

Comment: for using database query, you should be able to achieve it with [meta-data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario.html#meta-data) `sqlQuery`. For API testing using  qaf you can refer [qaf-wf-support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki)